# Where is the "watch position" information in Youtube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I would like to get the "watch position" of my watched videos, from the watch history, using Youtube API.

I do use `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?` to get my history, but so far I do not find the information I need.

What I call "watch position" is an information giving you the watch position in a video that you have already started, visually it is the red bar in screenshot below:

[image: screenshot from youtube]

Thanks

Comment: I've also checked the documentation, however, it seems that it's not yet supported. You may file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Enhancement%20Request)) for this.